# How to install Xcode 3.2.x on Lion?

Tags: xcode, osx-lion

I have tried to install Xcode 3.2.x on Lion using two methods below, but both failed.
Did anyone succeed with that two methods?

**Method 1**:

1. right click on "Xcode and iOS SDK.mpkg" and choose show package content;
2. modify the Contents/iPhoneSDKSL.dist to replace "10.7" with "10.8" in it;
3. install.

**Method 2**:

1. open the terminal;
2. export COMMAND_LINE_INSTALL=1;
3. open "/Volumes/Xcode and iOS SDK/Xcode and iOS SDK.mpkg"
4. uncheck all but the first one that include sdk and ide to install.

Besides, I also tried to use both two methods together, but failed again.

Any help?

Comment: Since you asked: yes, method 2 works for us.  How is it failing for you?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I'm not sure if you can do this. Because Xcode 3 it's too old for Lion. But there might be some kind of hack.

Comment: Yes, I think Xcode 4 is enough for coding and must be better than Xcode 3. For the reason that I want to learn some development under Mac OS X, but all books about that used Xcode 3. So I tried to install Xcode 3. However, I failed. THX to u all the same.

Comment: @mjt0704 I can try to find some books for you that is using Xcode 4. I'm sure enough that there is a lot.

Comment: @mjt0704 Do you need information specifically on Cocoa and Mac OS X Development?

Comment: @mjt0704 Loon on this: http://www.amazon.com/Cocoa-Programming-Mac-4th-Edition/dp/0321774086/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1334327813&sr=8-1

Comment: Thank you. I found some later.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set system clock back in time. It failed for me because of old certificate. I used 6th of May 2011